# Is there a way to detect highlighted key replacing by a keypress / keydown event?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am working on an angular7 app and I need to format customer input on an input field.

I am using the `keydown` event to track user input:

```
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    // Format user input (i.e. Capitalize word, etc)
  }
```

Now I am facing a problem of identifying user input while there is a value on the field, and which is going to replace with the current event (start typing on a highlighted field). In this case, the value of the Element will be the original value, and formatting that I do for that is not retained as it replaces the value.

Is there a way to identify whether the value of the field is highlighted or not at this moment?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you would like to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: Can you share a minimal version of your app in stackblitz? As far as I understood, you are trying to capture the key events of an `<input>` element. If that is the case, you can add the events directly on your `<input>` element as follows: `<input type='text' (keyup)="handleKeyEvent($event)">`. Now you have to handle your formatting logic in the `handleKeyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent)` method

Comment: Thanks @Shravan keyup does what I really wanted. But in this case I need to reserve keyup action for another. I think your example is what I really expected to get done.